# Find an integer $a$ such that $(x-a)(x-10)+1=(x-b)(x-c)$ for some integers $b$ and $c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math, roots

Can someone help with this Olympiad question?

> Find an integer $a$ such that $$(x-a) (x-10) +1$$ can be factored as $$(x-b) (x-c)$$ with $b$ and $c$ integer.

Comment: You really need to show some work - there are some easy things to try, and you will only learn to do unseen and unfamiliar problems by putting in the effort and seeing what works. If I simply tell you, you have learned very little.

Comment: As a hint I should also say that there is a method which requires rather less work than the first two answers people have given - it is worth finding, though it is not so general.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The discriminant $(a+10)^2-4(10a+1)=(a-10)^2-4=(a-8)(a-12)$ is a perfect square. Alternatively, show that $|b-10|=1$.

Comment: It seems more appropriate to say *"**if** the expression can be factored, **then**..."*.

Comment: This is a hint, not a full solution.  The OP can add such nuances himself.

Answer (score 2):

You want $b+c=a+10$ and $bc=10a+1$, which implies
$$
bc=10(b+c-10)+1=10(b+c)-100+1
$$
hence
$$
c=\frac{10b-100+1}{b-10}=10+\frac{1}{b-10}
$$
Can you go on?